# ObjectMapper deserializing required fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

Let's say i have such json and i would like to deserialize it to an object called SubscriberProfile.

```
{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", "field3": "value3" }
```

When i use following code it works without any problem,

```
objectMapper.readValue(json,SubscriberProfile.class);
```

but i want objectmapper throw and exception if field2 is missing in json (field1 and field2 can be missing).

so such json should throw an exception

```
{ "field1": "value1", "field3": "value3" }
```

I've tried to use `@JsonProperty(required=true)` annotation but works only when serialize it.

Do you have any idea how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In short; jackson doesn't validate on deserialization - you'll need to validate the object post deserialization, eg using hibernate-validator (the reference implementation of JSR-303)

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the default constructor for your bean class. It's what allows Jackson to create a bean without your required field. For example (modified from [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html)):

```
public class NonDefaultBean {
    private final String myRequired;
    private String myNotRequired;

    @JsonCreator
    public NonDefaultBean(@JsonProperty("myRequired") String myRequired) {
        this.myRequired = myRequired;
    }

    public void setMyNotRequired(String myNotRequired) {
        this.myNotRequired = myNotRequired;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have expected `required=false` on the `@JsonProperty` to have the same effect but it doesn't.